# Extending rep to matrices?

Tags: r, generics, matrix, replicate, r-s3

If you call `rep` on a matrix, it repeats its elements rather than the entire matrix. The traditional fix is to call `rep(list(theMatrix),...)`. I want to extend `rep` so that it does this automatically.

I attempted to use

```
rep.matrix<-function(x,...) rep(list(x),...)
```

which did indeed add `rep.matrix` to `methods(rep)`

```
> methods(rep)
[1] rep.bibentry*       rep.Date            rep.factor          rep.matrix         
[5] rep.numeric_version rep.POSIXct         rep.POSIXlt         rep.roman*         
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

However, calling rep on a matrix did not appear to dispatch to `rep.matrix`.

```
> rep(diag(5),3)
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
[42] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Although direct calls to `rep.matrix` worked without error.

```
> rep.matrix(diag(5),3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

I get the same outcomes if I create and use `rep.array` instead of `rep.matrix`.

Where is my error? Why isn't `rep` dispatching to `rep.matrix`? Did I use the wrong object system somehow?

Comment: Looks like a bug in `rep()`.  You should report it.

Comment: @user2554330 How did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. [The documentation is not too forthcoming about this fact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66338391/10319707), but `rep` is an **internal** generic function, as explained [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/InternalMethods.html). This means that it will only dispatch to things where `is.object` returns `TRUE`. Matrices are not such a thing, so you cannot extend `rep` to matrices and have it dispatch to them.