# Do any generic functions in the base library dispatch on matrices?

Tags: r, generics, matrix, r-s3, single-dispatch

I'm having some trouble [writing some code that dispatches on matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66284726/10319707). To assist me, I'd like to see what generic functions in the base library dispatch on matrices. Is there any way to get R to give me a list of them? Failing that, does anyone know of any members of that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least seven functions in base R that have matrix generics:

- `anyDuplicated`
- `determinant`
- `duplicated`
- `isSymmetric`
- `subset`
- `summary`
- `unique`

you can get them with

```
getS3method("anyDuplicated", class="matrix")
```

or just

```
anyDuplicated.matrix
```

Found using

```
Filter(function(x) {
  !is.null(getS3method(x, class="matrix", optional=TRUE))
},ls(all.names=TRUE, env = baseenv()))
```

Comment: Are you sure about that code at the bottom? When I run it, I get `character(0)` and `Warning message:
In findGeneric(f, envir) :
  'kronecker' is a formal generic function; S3 methods will not likely be found`

Comment: @J.Mini I get that warning too. Seems safe enough to ignore. I removed the explicit check for `isGeneric` which should be more forgiving. I may have had a different package loaded which changed the default behavior.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick. My output is now: ```[1] "anyDuplicated" "as.data.frame" "determinant"   "duplicated"   
[5] "isSymmetric"   "subset"        "summary"       "unique"       
Warning message:
In findGeneric(f, envir) :
  'kronecker' is a formal generic function; S3 methods will not likely be found```